# JsonMappingException using Spring Data REST: Selects wrong serializer when @Id is removed from the list that that is being mapped

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, spring-data-rest

I've created a [project on gitlab(url)](https://gitlab.com/snygaard/kado/tree/25fd9a20b790caf79519685f51e23f7a1d869a40) where I want to use Spring Data REST to persist and expose some sensor data. When testing with the HAL browser, persisting to the PostgreSQL DB was no problem but the SensorReading GET gave me some trouble:

> Could not write JSON: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resources[\"_embedded\"]>java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap[\"sensorReadings\"]>java.util.ArrayList[0]>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer$1[\"content\"]->net.smurfz.kado.models.SensorReading[\"sensorId\"])

The code in my @Entity-class (net.smurfz.kado.models.SensorReading):

```
@Entity
public class SensorReading {

    @Id
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sensor_reading_id_seq",
            sequenceName = "sensor_reading_id_seq",
            allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "sensor_reading_id_seq")
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private Integer sensorId;

    @NotNull
    private double reading;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private Date created;

    public SensorReading() {
    }

    public SensorReading(Integer sensorId, double reading) {
        this.sensorId = sensorId;
        this.reading = reading;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getSensorId() {
        return sensorId;
    }

    public void setSensorId(Integer sensorId) {
        this.sensorId = sensorId;
    }

    public double getReading() {
        return reading;
    }

    public void setReading(double reading) {
        this.reading = reading;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created = new Date();
    }
}
```

and my @RepositoryRestResource-class (net.smurfz.kado.repositories.SensorReadingRepository):

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface SensorReadingRepository extends CrudRepository<SensorReading, Integer> {
    List<SensorReading> findTop30BySensorIdOrderByCreatedDesc(Integer sensorId);
    Long countAllBySensorId(Integer sensorId);
    SensorReading findFirstBySensorIdOrderByCreatedDesc(Integer sensorId);
    Page<SensorReading> findAllBySensorId(Integer sensorId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Now the quickfix that my esteemed colleague managed to discover was to move:

```
        @Id
        @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "sensor_reading_id_seq",
                sequenceName = "sensor_reading_id_seq",
                allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = "sensor_reading_id_seq")
        @Column(updatable = false)
        private Integer id;
```

Under all the other field declarations.

This error occurs somewhere around when the BeanSerializerFactory-class tries to define which serializer to use. My working theory is that it initially recognizes 4 fields (list of 4), then filters away the id to not be serialized (list of 3), but decides to use the index (1-3) from the first list on the second list, resulting in the Integer field getting the serializer of the double field defined below.

This is a dirty hack that should not be needed and since I don't really know what other things this might affect down the road I would like to know:

a) why is this happening?

b) what should be done differently to avoid this error?

URL above links directly to the commit from before the implementation of the id-fix.

Comment: Hi - I think is similar to my issue - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147729/spring-boot-and-spring-data-rest?noredirect=1#comment77265008_45147729 and 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9756 andhttps://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1612

Comment: @Damien did you try the ugly fix in my post, and if yes, did it solve the immediate issue?

Comment: I didnt no - based on this jira - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9756. Changing the version to 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT resolves the issue.

Comment: @Damien Holy crap, thank you so much! ^^, That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote comment from @Damien:

> I didnt no - based on this jira -
>   github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9756. Changing the
>   version to 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT resolves the issue. – Damien

springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' solves this issue.